# No puedo instalalr Latino en ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: latino

[tengo mi ordenador en valenciano, y he copiado los resultados] pongo:
 sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev
pero me sale:
S'està llegint la llista de paquets… Fet
S'està construint l'arbre de dependències
S'està llegint la informació de l'estat… Fet
E: No s'ha trobat el paquet libreadline-dev

Comment: ¿Has probado a actualizar la lista de paquetes disponibles ? sudo apt-get update

Comment: si, la he actualizado

Comment: Has probado a descargar el paquete e instalarlo manualmente? El paquete lo puedes encontrar en: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libreadline-dev y un pequeño manual de como descargarlo e instalarlo: https://noviello.it/es/como-instalar-archivos-deb-paquetes-en-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recientemente termine de crear un script que permite la instalacion de Latino y todas sus librerias y dependencias para Linux (Solo Linux, no mac)

Aqui te lo comparto, solo tienes que abrir tu terminal, copiar y pegar este script y el script hara todo por ti, solo te pedira por el admin password.

```
git clone https://github.com/lenguaje-latino/instalacion.git && cd instalacion && sudo chmod +x latino_instalacion-linux.sh && ./latino_instalacion-linux.sh
```

Si quieres aprender mas sobre la instalacion de Latino en Ubuntu, mira la documentacion aqui:

https://manual.lenguajelatino.org/es/stable/OS/Debian-Ubuntu.html